# Help translating the phrase, "was seen as."

Tags: translation

The sentence I am trying to translate: "Revolution was seen as desperate and dangerous."
I am aware of the grammar pattern, sb 把革命视为危险的 for "see as." However, this usage is incorrect because the object following 视为 needs to be a noun, and the subject is unspecified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the meaning slightly so I could use 被视为危险的行为, which did not require specifying a subject.

Comment: Why are you using 行为 here?

Comment: Because it is mandated by use of 视为, which can only be followed by a noun.

Comment: Your translation sounds natural. But I'd like to point out that using 视为 without a subject is also accepted, because 行为 is implied here. If I were to translate this sentence without plugging in an additional noun, I might feel that something like 革命被视为孤注一掷而且危险的 is more natural, with 视为 being followed by two adjectives so they won't be "dangling" there. But maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 3):

I think "be seen as" can be translated as "被视为"/"被看作"/"被认为"/"在...眼里看来是".

As you mentioned, there should a noun following "视为", so we need to add it, however, in some informal situation, like in speaking Chinese, without this noun it's still ok.

In some case of English-Chinese translation, it is very common to change passive voice into active voice to indicate the subject by context, which is more close to Chinese language. In the translation below I use "People"(人们) as the subject, which can be changed in the certain context.

Here is my translation of "Revolution was seen as desperate and dangerous."

（过去）变革在人们眼里看来是铤而走险的举动。

（过去）搞革命被人们视作是铤而走险的举动。

（过去）人们认为变革是铤而走险的举动。

（过去）人们视搞革命为铤而走险的举动。

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a problem. Because these usage（adj as noun） are quite often seen in 文言文，it also exist in modern Chinese。

至于幽暗昏惑而无物以相之 （幽暗昏惑，形容词作名词，叫人疑惑的地方）

Answer (score 0):

革命曾经被视为一种孤注一掷、铤而走险的行为。

And here is only for 30 characters restriction.